# How to modify behavior of workspace navigator in Gnome 3.10?

Tags: gnome, workspaces

With Gnome 3.10, how can I change the default behavior of the workspace navigator? The default is an up / down navigator without circular switching (i.e., moving from down from the bottom-last workspace does not bring me to the top-most workspace)? Also, I would prefer left-right to up-down.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/). It supports both up-down and left-right workspace navigation.

Comment: Thank you; sounds interesting! However, I did not manage to install it under Gnome 3.10.

Comment: Oops; sorry about that. It is apparently an [open issue](https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension/issue/13/support-for-gnome-310). If you're feeling adventurous, you could try installing the extension from [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension/pull-request/4/update-extension-to-gnome-310/diff), which supports 3.10.